# Next.js 14. App Router. How to add custom class on body tag without activating 'use client'

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I am using **App Router** (Next.js 14). I am also using the default setup, where the body tag is in the @/app/layout.js:

```
import Header from '@/components/Layout/Header/Header'
import Footer from '@/components/Layout/Footer/Footer'

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Need to be able provide custom styling at least for **page.js** level

```
<body class="custom-class" id="custom-id">...</body>
```

Is it possible pass it up the tree **without** activating `'use client'`?

so /example/page.js /example/example/pages.js can have its own classes

Comment: Doing that in the root layout doesn't make much sense, since it is only rendered on the initial page load and not after navigation. You can use something like a css [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector or [route groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups). You could also consider styling a div inside the body instead, which can change per page.

Comment: Thank you. That actually helped :) I keep forgetting about ":has"